# Oracle 11g 32 bit and 64 bit versions on Windows 7

Tags: oracle, windows-7, oracle11g

Can I install 32 and 64 bit versions of Oracle on same windows 7 Operating System? And if it can be done, how?

Comment: Yes.  Install into separate oracle homes. However, one of them has to take precedence in your PATH environment.

Comment: Are you asking about the client or the server?

Comment: On a 64bit Windows, only a 64bit Oracle is supported (the 32bit version basically works, but does have some problems)

Comment: @ThiyaguATR: English please.

Comment: hey...'m asking have you tried this on your system?which OS your using?if you get any error message post that also!